# Make triangle using java

Tags: java, loops

```
   public class PrintTriangleMirror
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    int height =7;
    for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++)
    {
    // Print out row number of cells, on the same line.
    for (int column = 1; column <= row; column++)
    System.out.print("[_]");

     System.out.println();
       } 

      }
       }
```

i want to end up with a triangle like this but code i just created do the opposite

[image]

Comment: You'll need to insert some spaces.

Comment: Do for starting from `row` and ending in 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (just inverse the order of row from hieght to 1 and add another loop to print spaces):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int height =7;

    for (int row = height; row > 0; row--)
    {

        for(int space = row; space < height ; space++)

            System.out.print("   ");


        for (int column = 1; column <= row; column++)

            System.out.print("[_]");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output for height = 7:

```
[_][_][_][_][_][_][_]
   [_][_][_][_][_][_]
      [_][_][_][_][_]
         [_][_][_][_]
            [_][_][_]
               [_][_]
                  [_]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there you just need to insert some spaces like so:

```
public class PrintTriangleMirror {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    int height = 7;
    for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++) {
      for (int space = 1; space < row; space++) {
          System.out.print("   ");
      }
      for (int column = 1; column <= height - row + 1; column++) {
        System.out.print("[_]");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[_][_][_][_][_][_][_]
   [_][_][_][_][_][_]
      [_][_][_][_][_]
         [_][_][_][_]
            [_][_][_]
               [_][_]
                  [_]
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FuSU/0)